# How to use AutoForm to register users and login?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I want to use AutoForm to create a register form which subsequetnly creates users. Furtehremore, new users should be signed in automatically after registering.

Therefore, I created an AutoForm and supplied a `meteormethod` called `signUp`:

```
Meteor.methods({
    signUp: function (doc) {
        check(doc, Schema.signUp);
        Accounts.createUser({username: doc.username, password: doc.password});
    }
});
```

This works perfect. However, I don't know how I can login users from server side? Is this even possible?

If not, how can I solve this issue? Do I need to include `Accounts.createUser({username: doc.username, password: doc.password});` in my Schema `custom` validation function?

Comment: Check out the useraccounts packages on Atmosphere. That's probably what you want, although not an answer to this question

Comment: also, don't put `Accounts.createUser` in a `custom` validation function. and could you explain exactly what the problem is with your method not signing you in? what do you mean to log someone in server side? which client gets logged in?

Answer (score 1):

To use `aldeed:autoform` with any collection, you first need to define *schema* to that collection because `autoform` relies on `simple-schema` attached to that collection. Without schema, the form won't appear and you'll see an uncaught exception thrown by autoform.

So at first, you need to define schema. After that, it's possible to update or insert users into `Meteor.users` collection. See the official docs for the typical plain-object structure of a users collection entity, at first you may just `console.log` currently authenticated `Meteor.user()` to see what required fields it has.

My personal advice would be to not use autoform to mess around with users. It's not very secure and you need to explicitly control what users (or roles) can CRUD your users and what users do not. That's just extra pain to solve, and it may simply negate the convenience of autoform.

Comment: Also, see [this discussion](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/607). I believe it can help a lot.